# Authenticate to private npm registry from Dockerfile in azure?

Tags: azure, docker, npm, azure-devops

I have the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR ./usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/

COPY .npmrc ./

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start-prod"]
```

This file is used in an azure pipeline like so:

```yaml
variables:
  - name: NPMRC_LOCATION
    value: $(Agent.TempDirectory)
    
  - stage: BuildPublishDockerImage
    displayName: Build and publish Docker image
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildPublishDockerImage
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            name: npmrc
            inputs:
              secureFile: .npmrc
          - task: npmAuthenticate@0
            inputs:
              workingFile: $(NPMRC_LOCATION)/.npmrc
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build a Docker image
            inputs:
              command: build
              arguments: --no-cache
```

I know `.npmrc` should be in that location (I run `RUN ls` in the Dockerfile and its there).
However when I run it I keep getting this error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/.npmrc" not found: not found

I just want to authenticate to a private npm registry.  I'm mystified by this.  Grateful for any help.

Comment: In your dockerfile you just copy from the context but in your other task you indicate that the .npmrc is at `$(NPMRC_LOCATION)/.npmrc`. Are you sure this lines up? I would also advise to mount it as secret during the RUN instruction that containes npm install, to avoid capturing it permanently in a layer.

Comment: how do you successfully do `RUN ls` if the build fails with that error?

Answer (score 0):

You can in Dockerfile set registry

```
npm config set registry
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what does this action do?